# jenkins env variable is shared among branch and master or not?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

This is some part of my Jenkins pipeline code to trigger build after setting certain parameters, I am setting these env variables from the master and from branches as well. I know my master and branches can trigger builds independently(simultaneously).

Is it possible they(branch build and master build) are sharing this env variable exposed by Jenkins? Or they have their own copy of env variable?

```
// determine current quadrant using system time
    def quadrant = getCurrentQuadrant()
    env.TRIGGER_TYPE=getTriggerType()
    echo "Current quadrant: " + quadrant + " | triggertype: " + env.TRIGGER_TYPE
    env.ENV = "${environment}"

//if the build is triggered by timer in first/fourth quarter of 24 hrs day then change default trigger<dev> to <staging>
if  ( (quadrant == 0 || quadrant == 3 ) && env.TRIGGER_TYPE =='Started by timer') { 
    env.ENV = "staging"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are environment variables that *are* shared: "[Working with the Environment](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#working-with-the-environment)": the `JENKINS_URL` and others

The rules are:

> - An environment directive used in the top-level pipeline block will apply to all steps within the Pipeline.
> - An environment directive defined within a stage will only apply the given environment variables to steps within the stage.

So if your steps involve multiple branches, they will share the same environment variables.
But if those branches are used independently, in separate run of the same pipeline job, thet would not.
An alternative would be to use [parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#parameters) for runtime-specific values.

You can find [another approach in this gist](https://gist.github.com/tonespy/dd1afbb9d62d879d0ae6d8136ea4e4f6):

```
stage('Deploy application') {
    // This is the cool part where you deploy. Here, you can specify builds you want to deploy
    switch (env.BRANCH_NAME) {
        case "master":
            sh("env >> .env")
            sh("docker run --env-file .env --rm ${project} ./gradlew clean build assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease")
            sh("rm -rf .env")
            break
        case "dev":
            sh("env >> .env")
            sh("docker run --env-file .env --rm ${project} ./gradlew clean build assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug")
            sh("rm -rf .env")
            break
    }
}
```

Running a Jenkins pipeline step in a docker with `--env-file .env` would allow a build to share a common set of variables stored in `.env`.

Comment: See also http://codegist.net/search/jenkinsfile-build-parameters/6 and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41748